Memory limits set in your systemd slice are not being enforced correctly
I try to run process with memory and CPU limit but looks like it is not working and I keep running the process bigger than the memory limits. This is what I have:

My /etc/systemd/system/group750m.slice
[Slice]
MemoryLimit=750M
CPUQuota=50%


Then I do:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start group750m.slice
sudo systemctl status group750m.slice


Results:
group750m.slice
Loaded: loaded
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/group750m.slice.d
└─10-limits.conf

Active: active since Tue 2024-07-16 07:56:24 UTC; 11h ago
Tasks: 7
Memory: 254.8M (limit: 750.0M)

CGroup: /group750m.slice
└─group750m.scope
└─12569 /home/vagrant/go/projects/1m_test/1m-go-websockets/4_optimize_gobwas/4_optimize_gobwas



Running the app:
sudo systemd-run --unit=group750m --slice=group750m.slice --scope /bin/bash -c '/home/vagrant/go/projects/1m_test/1m-go-websockets/4_optimize_gobwas/4_optimize_gobwas'

But when I do top on the running process in its peak it is more then Gb RAM
top - 19:25:46 up 1 day, 9:31, 7 users, load average: 2.38, 2.30, 1.28
Tasks: 1 total, 0 running, 1 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu0 : 10.5 us, 14.3 sy, 0.0 ni, 69.4 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 5.8 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu1 : 3.8 us, 6.8 sy, 0.0 ni, 84.9 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 4.5 si, 0.0 st
MiB Mem : 3932.3 total, 1035.4 free, 1364.8 used, 1532.1 buff/cache
MiB Swap: 2048.0 total, 2048.0 free, 0.0 used. 2284.5 avail Mem

  PID USER PR NI    VIRT   RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM   TIME+ COMMAND
12569 root 20  0 1248192 69736 5072 S  7.3  1.7 0:39.81 4_optimize_gobw

What am I missing here?

TL/DR
The process is only using about 70MB of memory. Look at the RES field.
  PID USER PR NI    VIRT   RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM   TIME+
12569 root 20  0 1248192 69736 5072 S  7.3  1.7 0:39.81 
                            ^
                            |
 actual memory in use[1] ---+

Details
In the top output, only virtual memory (VIRT) is greater than 750MiB. Virtual is usually not what the user cares about in terms of limits, because much of the virtual memory is not backed by physical memory, nor is it swapped out. The available virtual address space on a 64-bit system is gigantic.
A more useful field is resident memory (RES/RSS), which is well under the systemd-specified memory limit.
MiB Swap: 2048.0 total, 2048.0 free, 0.0 used. 2284.5 avail Mem
                                      ^
                                      |
 no swap is being used ---------------+

This question on SuperUser explains the difference between virtual and resident memory.

(1) The kernel's implementation of cgroups (v1 in your case) has many subtleties and is way outside the scope of this question.
